# How can i request remote data after press enter? (mbrn/material-table)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using remote data example from material table, `The current behavior`

1. In `componentDidMount` the data request by default.
2. any search or sorting make by default another request to get data based on the new query
3. I can delay the request by providing `debounceInterval`

**`What I want to do?`**

1. I want when I`type in the global search`----> I don't want to get data by default unless I press `enter`

`And here is my render method that will make the table resolves the remote data once it's received the data`

```
        <Entity
          storeId={storeId}
          entityRef={ref => { this.entity = ref; }}
          onEntityReceived={data => this.onEntityReceived(data)}
          onEntityReceivedError={data => this.onEntityReceivedError(data)}
          render={store => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <If condition={this.exceptionError}>
                <Message variant={'warning'} text={this.exceptionError} />
              </If>

              <MaterialTable
                tableRef={ref => this.tableRef = ref}
                title={this.title}
                data={query => {
                  this.get(query);
                  return new Promise(resolve => event.on('data-fetched', resolve));
                }}
                isLoading={(store.loading && this.exceptionErrorsLoader) || isLoading}
                options={this.options}
                actions={this.actions}
                localization={this.localization}
                columns={this.columns}
                components={this.components}
                icons={this.icons}
                detailPanel={this.rowDetailsPanel}
                onRowClick={onRowClick}
              />
```

`Here is the code that will handle received data to provide it to the table`

```
  onEntityReceived(data) {
    this.exceptionErrorsLoader = false;

    event.notify('data-fetched', {
      page: this.state.pageIndex,
      totalCount: data.totalCount,
      data,
    });
  }
```

`This is the get method that will get the data from server`

```
  get(query) {
    const { oldQuery } = this.state;
    const { additionalEntityPayload } = this.props;
    const serverSideLink = this.getServerSideLink(query);
       
    this.exceptionErrorsLoader = true;
    this.setState({ 
      query,
      // ======== In Order To Save FIRST_QUERY (in case we need to refresh old data)
      oldQuery: isEmpty(oldQuery) ? query : oldQuery,
      pageIndex: query.page,
      pageSize: query.pageSize,
    }, () => {
      if(!isEmpty(additionalEntityPayload)) {
        return this.entity.get({ 
          serverSideLink, additionalPayload: additionalEntityPayload });
      }

      this.entity.get({ serverSideLink });
    });
  }
```

**`The issue is I don't know how to control the search field or other field because they are not exposed`**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?